# Bot Framework LUIS on Teams OnPrem

Tags: docker, botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-language-understanding

I'm new in BotFramework and maybe you can help me.

I need to create a bot with LUIS and vinculate it to a MS Teams channel. As far I see, there are not any problem in making this approach directly on Azure, but because of the elevated price I'm looking for the possibily  to make it onPrem due to costs reduction.

I have seen that deploy a BOT with a Docker container OnPrem is possible. There are any restriction I should know before start?

Comment: You can create and upload a bot to teams. Could you please check this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/build-your-first-app/build-bot)

Comment: Yes, i know but I want if I have to prevent any issue on onprem deploy

Comment: Are you facing any issue while deploying the manifest?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft allow the pages which are publicly available. You can able to access the Public HTML pages. Also You can create and upload a bot to teams. Could you please check this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/build-your-first-app/build-bot).